# How to put variable in a query?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to filter data from database by adding a variable into the query. The query that I have made is like this:

```
$data = $this->db->query('SELECT channel, MIN(product_name) as product_name, SUM(revenue) AS revenue FROM my_test_table WHERE channel = "chanel1" AND province=$area GROUP BY SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3)')->result();
```

But it result in this message:

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '$area' in 'where clause'

I use the "$area" variable in the query to make it dynamically filter the data based on the input from the user. So the $area is a variable that assign any value from the input.

Comment: If this variable contains user supplied data, this would be prone to an SQL injection. Please properly [escape the string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the codeigniter way for your example is:

```
$data = $this->db->select('channel, MIN(product_name) as product_name, SUM(revenue) AS revenue')
                 ->where('channel','chanel1')
                 ->where('province',$area)
                 ->group_by('SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3)')
                 ->get('my_test_table')
                 ->result();
```

Codeigniter [Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#query-builder-class), it creates a query string, which escapes the columns properly

Answer (score 0):

> $data = $this->db->query('SELECT channel, MIN(product_name) as
>   product_name, SUM(revenue) AS revenue FROM my_test_table WHERE channel
>   = "chanel1" AND province='.$area.' GROUP BY SUBSTRING(product_name, 1, 3)')->result();

Note this solution probably is not secure. The variable can be SQL injected. I write the solution under your consideration.